# How to set ntasks or ntasks-per-node in slurm for running multi-node distributed training in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, slurm

I want to run the official video classification script [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/tree/master/references/video_classification).

I plan to run it on slurm machine.
I am not sure how to properly set the SBATCH argument `--ntasks` or `--ntasks-per-node`  if I want to run this script on 2 nodes with 8 V100 GPUs each.
like `--ntasks 16`
or `--ntasks-per-node 8` ?
Any advice? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the python code does not explicitly start multiple Slurm tasks, then you should go with this in your job script:

```
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --gpus-per-node=8
```

This would give your script one Slurm task with access to 8 GPUs on each node. If you need more CPU or memory (maybe you do some pre/postprocessing?), you can add

```
#SBATCH --mem=10G
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=8
```

Comment: Why 1 task per node, shouldn't the task number be set to the number of GPUs per node?